# VB.net adding items to List(of T) issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, generic-list

I'm loading a list with 7 objects, but the objects get "overwritten" with the last object that is added. There are 7 objects that get created (Exec, Mgr, Position...etc) the 1st one "Exec" is added to the list correctly, but each new OrgShape that is created overwrites all the OrgShapes that have been previously added to the list. I know I'm missing something easy...

```
Public Shared Function GetOrgShapeData() As List(Of OrgShape)
    Dim OgrShapeList As New List(Of OrgShape)
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = HR_DB.GetConnection
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VisioShapeDim"
    Dim selectCommand As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader
        Dim orgshape As OrgShape
        Do While reader.Read
            orgshape = New OrgShape

            orgshape.ShapeName = reader("ShapeName")
            orgshape.ShapeWidth = reader("ShapeWidth")
            orgshape.ShapeHeight = reader("ShapeHeight")

            OgrShapeList.Add(orgshape)
            orgshape = Nothing
        Loop
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Throw ex
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    Return OgrShapeList
End Function
```

'**Added OrgShape Class

```
Public Class OrgShape
  Private Shared m_ShapeName As String
  Private Shared m_ShapeWidth As Double
  Private Shared m_ShapeHeight As Double

  Public Sub New()

  End Sub

  Public Shared Property ShapeName() As String
    Get
        Return m_ShapeName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_ShapeName = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Shared Property ShapeWidth() As Double
    Get
        Return m_ShapeWidth
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        m_ShapeWidth = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Shared Property ShapeHeight() As Double
    Get
        Return m_ShapeHeight
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        m_ShapeHeight = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Please show the code for `OrgShape`. (In particular, if your properties are shared, that would explain things...) Additionally, consider using a `Using` statement instead of explicitly using try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `Shared` keyword from your properties and variables, since you are looking for instances:

```
Public Class OrgShape
  Private m_ShapeName As String
  Private m_ShapeWidth As Double
  Private m_ShapeHeight As Double

  Public Property ShapeName() As String
    Get
      Return m_ShapeName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      m_ShapeName = value
    End Set
  End Property
```

See [Shared (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the following line

```
orgshape = Nothing
```

You're erasing your object each time.

Remember in .NET Objects are `reference` types.

Edit based on question edit. You also can't used shared fields and properties for instance data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Dim orgshape As new OrgShape` in the loop and remove `orgshape = New OrgShape` and `orgshape = Nothing`